# PHP array as input into a Javascript Google Ganttchart

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization, gantt-chart

I try to create a Ganttchart from a PHP array.

My PHP Code looks like:

```
<?php
$ganttData = [
    ['Project Start', 'Project Start', '2023-08-01', '2023-08-02'],
    ['Gate1', 'Gate1', '2023-08-28', '2023-08-28'],
    ['Gate2', 'Gate2', '2024-01-30', '2024-03-04'],
    ['PD Start', 'PD Start', '2024-03-04', '2024-03-04']
];

// Encode data to JSON
$ganttDataJson = json_encode($ganttData);
?>
```

The HTML / Javascript looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gantt']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
    data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
    data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
    var ganttData = <?php echo $ganttDataJson; ?>;
    ganttData.forEach(function(row) {
    // Split the date string into year, month, and day
    var startDateParts = row[2].split('-');
    var endDateParts = row[3].split('-');
    // Convert date string to Date object
    row[2] = new Date(parseInt(startDateParts[0]), parseInt(startDateParts[1]) - 1, parseInt(startDateParts[2]));
    row[3] = new Date(parseInt(endDateParts[0]), parseInt(endDateParts[1]) - 1, parseInt(endDateParts[2]));
            
    // Calculate duration in milliseconds
    var startDate = new Date(row[2]);
    var endDate = new Date(row[3]);
    var durationInMilliseconds = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    row[4] = durationInMilliseconds;
    });
    data.addRows(ganttData);
    var options = {
    height: 400,
        gantt: {
        trackHeight: 30
        }
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get always an error message.
"Invalid data table format: column #5 must be of type 'number'.×"
As I don't have a lot of experience with javascript, I appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you get when you log `durationInMilliseconds`?

Comment: It should probably not matter regarding the outcome, but `var startDate = new Date(row[2]);` - `row[2]` here is already a Date instance, no need to create a _new_ one from it. And the whole `// Split the date string into year, month, and day` is also not necessary - `YYYY-MM-DD` is a format the Date constructor parses perfectly fine.

Comment: console.log(typeof durationInMilliseconds) will give 'number'; console.log(durationInMilliseconds) will give values between 0 and 2937600000

Comment: Thank you for the comment on var start date. In that case, I would receive an error message, that the format is not a date.

Comment: I found it... The data format was wrong.... 
see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51644687/google-chart-invalid-data-table-format

Comment: @Jan I recommend closing or deleting your question then, as the question is quite long and trying to focus on it doesn't make sense as there was no actual problem other than the wrong type usage